# Javascript: How to filter object in array

Tags: javascript, filter

I have an array that is consisted of object which has categoryName(string) field and an array(plants).

I'd like to filter using plant name, what's the best approach?

I tried with but it only returns plants array, ignores categoryName

```
this.itemList.map(item => item.plants.filter(p=> p.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase())));
```

Structure

```
[

 [
    categoryName: "Heating"
    plants: Array(2)
    0: {plantId: 35, name: "Alston Oven", description: "Oven", plantCategoryId: 2, whenCreated: "1519357215942", …}
    1: {plantId: 19, name: "Gregs Oven", description: null, plantCategoryId: 2, whenCreated: "1516830724579", …}
 ]



  [
    categoryName: "Refrigeration"
    plants: Array(4)
    0: {plantId: 13, name: "Fridge 1 ", description: "Walk in fridge" …}
    1: {plantId: 5, name: "Fridge 2 Updated", description: "Description of Fridge 2" …}
    2: {plantId: 4, name: "Fridge"....} 
  ]
]
```

Comment: Try using: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Are you sure it's a correct structure, I guess it's `console` result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
this.itemList.map(function(a) {
    return {
        categoryName: a.categoryName,
        plants: a.plants.filter(p => p.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
}}).filter(a => a.plants.length > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()` on the outer array and `some()` on the inner `plants` array.

This will not filter out the specific plant(s) within the plants array but keep the whole array intact. It is not clear whether you need to filter the sub array or not

```
const term = this.searchTerm.toLowerCase(),
      res = this.itemList.filter(({plants}) => plants.some(({name}) => name.toLowerCase().includes(term)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this example

```js
const searchTerm = "Alston";
const itemList = [
  {
    categoryName: "Heating",
    plants: [
      {
        plantId: 35,
        name: "Alston Oven",
        description: "Oven",
        plantCategoryId: 2,
        whenCreated: "1519357215942",
      },
      {
        plantId: 19,
        name: "Gregs Oven",
        description: null,
        plantCategoryId: 2,
        whenCreated: "1516830724579",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    categoryName: "Refrigeration",
    plants: [
      { plantId: 13, name: "Fridge 1 ", description: "Walk in fridge" },
      {
        plantId: 5,
        name: "Fridge 2 Updated",
        description: "Description of Fridge 2",
      },
      { plantId: 4, name: "Fridge" },
    ],
  },
];

const output = itemList.filter((item) => {
  return item.plants
    .map((entry) => entry.name.toLowerCase())
    .join()
    .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
});

console.dir(output, { depth: null, color: true });
```

See

- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to filter the `plants` arrays, you don't need to use `map`. Use `forEach()`, and then reassign the `plants` property with the filtered array there.

```
this.itemList.forEach(item => 
    item.plants = item.plants.filter(p => 
        p.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase())));
```